# How to access image from storage sub folder in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How to get image url with mimeType in laravel 8 from Storage sub folder.

My Folder look like this :

[image]

I want to access this image marked in red, So I did these steps:

Step 1 : Create Link using ** php artisan storage:link **

Then In my Controller :

```
$exists =  Storage::disk('public')->get('/app/media/HRTKD1607258351/HRTKD1607258351');
    if($exists) {
        return "File Found";
    }else{
        return "File Not Found";
    }
```

But I am getting File Not Found Error.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Storage::disk('public')->get('/app/media/HRTKD1607258351/HRTKD1607258351.jpg');`  here `.jpg` was missing

Comment: But I don't know there is .jpg or not, Then How I will access this. I uploaded many format like .jpg, .png  then ?

Comment: Using this **Storage::disk('public')->get('/app/media/HRTKD1607258351/HRTKD1607258351.jpg');**  also giving me file not found exception

Comment: then you may need only match the file name without extension to verify only

Comment: I already did but it is giving FileNotFound Exception @KamleshPaul

Comment: the default public path points to: app/public, maybe use the storage_path helper method? $path = storage_path('app/file.txt');

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` command will create.a symlink with path `storage/app/public` but your path is `storage/app/media` change it to _storage/app/public_ or _storage/app/public/media_

Comment: I did **php artisan storage:link** and Change path to **storage/app/public** But I am stilling the error if I don't use **.jpg**, I want to do like find the file without extension and if file present get the extension and display it on blade file @sta

Comment: Maybe it would be better to get a list of all files in the directory `$files = Storage::files($directory);` (or all files in the directory and all its subdirectories `$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);`) and then inside your controller find this file in the returned array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Storage::disk('media')->url('HRTKD1607258351/HRTKD1607258351.jpg');

Comment: In everycase I have to pass **.jpg** but I gave user to upload any extension image then how will I know that the particular image I am looking for is a **.jpg** extension ?

Comment: You can store the file name in DB , after that you can retrieve that, for example take the field in DB for file name and store this value : HRTKD1607258351/HRTKD1607258351.jpg after that you can use like that Storage::disk('media')->url($model->file_name);

Answer (score 0):

Specify the port that the application is using.

e.g set app url in **.env** to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`